# nullreferenceexception object reference not set to an instance of an object unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

this is my code for the player spawn but I'm getting a null reference exception error.

```cs
public class PlayerSpawn : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform playerSpawn;
    public Vector2 currentTrackPosition;
    public bool activeRespawnTimer = false;
    public float respawnTimer = 1.0f;
    public float resetRespawnTimer = 1.0f;

    void Start () 
    {       
        if(playerSpawn != null)
        {
            transform.position = playerSpawn.position;  
            Debug.Log(playerSpawn);
        }
    }
    
    void Update () 
    {
        if(activeRespawnTimer)
        {
            respawnTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
        
        if(respawnTimer <= 0.0f)
        {
            transform.position = currentTrackPosition;
            respawnTimer = resetRespawnTimer;
            activeRespawnTimer = false;
        }
    }
    
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        //im getting the error messege at this position
        if(other.tag == "DeadZone")
        {
            activeRespawnTimer = true;  
        }

        if(other.tag == "CheckPoint")
        {
            currentTrackPosition = transform.position;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem? Thank you for the help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the position you mention the null reference exception occurs, it appears as if either `other` or `other.tag` is null. Considering that `OnTriggerEnter` is only called when an actual object enters the trigger, I highly doubt that `other` is null, unless it's been destroyed prior to the method being called. In any case, it's better to be safe than sorry.

One simple solution would be the following:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(other != null && other.tag != null)
    {
        if(other.tag == "DeadZone")
        {
            activeRespawnTimer = true;  
        }

        if(other.tag == "CheckPoint")
        {
            currentTrackPosition = transform.position;
        }
    }
}
```

If this still throws an exception, then it must be something else that's causing the problem, so let me know how this works out.